# How do you add a control to a Canvas which implements a Drag/Resize adorner, programmatically?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, canvas, adorner

I have incorporated into my WPF project a drag/resize adorner that I found [here](https://denisvuyka.wordpress.com/2007/10/15/wpf-simple-adorner-usage-with-drag-and-resize-operations/).

I see that it works fine for controls added in xaml, but not for controls added to the Canvas programatically at runtime. Programatically added controls resize, but will not drag.

What can I add to the code so that controls generated at runtime will drag?
and, why do they not? - what difference is there between a control added at runtime and a control added in the xaml?

I have been using buttons but I think this applies to any control.

I found [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/408252/WPF-Dynamic-Dragging) article on the subject - but he doesn't use an adorner at all.

Comment: Last I knew [MouseDragElementBehavior](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn195664(v=vs.110).aspx) is still a valid behavior in the Blend Interaction Behaviors SDK you could ass to whatever UIElement.

Comment: Thank you Chris, being new to WPF, I didn't know about that. while I would still be grateful to have my question answered, thank you for putting me on the right track. When I add that behavior to an element with the adorner, it only drags when the adorner is "switched off". I am thinking of using TranslateZoomRotateBehavior - as the the programme is for a touchscreen - and ditching the adorner.